# Can't reach webserver from own ipv6 subnet but from outside

Tags: router, webserver, ipv6, radvd

I am really confused with my actual ipv6 setup in my home LAN. From my ISP I get an ipv6 /54 prefix. That prefix is assigned to the WAN interface of my router via DHCPv6 provided by the ISP. Then the wlan0 interface of my router should advertise this prefix into my LAN via radvd so that the hosts could do SLAAC. The config is:

```
interface wlan0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 9;
    AdvReachableTime 2000; 
    prefix ::/64 {
        AdvAutonomous on; 
        DeprecatePrefix on; 
    };
    route ::/0 {
    };
};
```

From now on everything is functioning properly. All the hosts in my LAN get ipv6 addresses and sites like whatismyip.com show that the hosts ipv6 connectivity works fine. Further I can ping ipv6-sites like ipv6.google.com.

However. The routing/advertising PC on my LAN runs a apache2 webserver. This server is up and running and assigned to the WAN interface IP on port 80 of the router. Now I can test the reachability from the internet by using [ipv6proxy.net](http://ipv6proxy.net). Everything works fine! But when I would like to ping this IP from the hosts in my LAN so I get a `Destination unreachable: Address unreachable` message back...

Is this a routing problem? What else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Indeed it was a routing issue. Per default the Linux kernel does not accept routing information from ICMPv6 messages, so I put

```
echo 128 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen
```

Optionally I could set the route via the wlan-interface manually by using:

```
route -6 add <prefix of WAN interface>/64 gw <address of wlan0 interface>
```

on the client situated in the LAN